# Debugging LINQ on a per-element basis

Tags: c#, linq, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I love LINQ statements for the expressive syntax and other convenient features. However, I find it very troublesome to debug them sometimes. Specifically, when I run a LINQ statement on a collection and one of the elements in the collection causes an exception, how can I figure out what the problem input was and where the problem came from?

Imagine I have a text file with 1000 real numbers:

```
0.46578
12.314213
1.444876
...
```

I am reading this as a `List<string>` and loading it into a more specific data structure:

```
var file_contents = File.ReadAllLines("myfile.txt");
var data = file_contents.Select(s => double.Parse(s));
```

Now, for this particular input, I didn't bother to look at it carefully and it turns out the 876th line contains (line numbers shown):

```
875    5.56786450
876    Error: Could not calculate value.
878    0.0316213
```

For whatever reason (perhaps the file was generated by a script that malfunctioned). My LINQ method chain will of course throw an exception. The problem is, how do I figure which element of the list caused the exception, and what its value was?

To clarify, if instead I used a for-loop:

```
var data = new List<double>();
foreach(var row in file_contents)
{
    var d = double.Parse(row);
    data.Add(d);
}
```

Then the exception would highlight the string which calls `double.Parse`, and I would be able to mouse over `row` to easily see what the problem input was.

I can, of course, use Resharper to convert my LINQ statements into for-loops, and then debug them, but is there a better way?

Comment: What kind of LINQ is this? EF or LINQ to SQL?

Answer (score 3):

Put a conditional breakpoint on the lambda function, where the condition is s.StartsWith("5.56").  You just need to have your cursor on the lambda and press F9.  Assuming you're using visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = file_contents.Select(s => {
    try
    {
       return double.Parse(s);

    }
    catch
    {
       throw; //breakpoint?
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: I work for OzCode*

LINQ debugging is hard borderline impossible using Visual Studio. I suggest you try using OzCode.

This is what your code looks when debugging (the exception in on the 6th item).
[image: Debugging LINQ exception]

You can tell which item caused the exception by investigating the items that where passed to the *Select* clause - and since the last one triggered the exception - it's easy to find the offending value.

If you're interested you can try OzCode's LINQ debugging - we've just started an [EAP](http://o.oz-code.com/LINQ_EAP)

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a tryparse personally.

```
        var data = new List<string>
            {
                "0.46578",
                "12.314213",
                "Error: Could not calculate value.",
                "1.444876",
            };
        double d;
        var good = data.Where(s => Double.TryParse(s, out d)).Select(Double.Parse);
        var bad = data.Where(s => !Double.TryParse(s, out d)).Select(x => new
            {
                key = data.IndexOf(x),
                value = x
            }).ToDictionary(x => x.key, x => x.value);


        textBox1.AppendTextAddNewLine("Good Data:");
        WriteDataToTextBox(good);

        textBox1.AppendTextAddNewLine(String.Format("{0}{0}Bad Data:", Environment.NewLine));
        WriteDataToTextBox(bad);
```

The AppendTextAddNewLine is simply an extension method I wrote for my little proof of concept test program

```
    public static void AppendTextAddNewLine(this TextBox textBox, string textToAppend)
    {
        textBox.AppendText(textToAppend + Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

**Edit**

The WriteDataToTextbox is a generic method that writes an `IEnumerble<T>` out to the text box.

```
    void WriteDataToTextBox<T>(IEnumerable<T> data )
    {
        foreach (var row in data)
        {
            textBox1.AppendTextAddNewLine(row.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Forgot to put the output here so I figure I should do that. It shows the index of the bad data and the data itself that caused the problem.

```
Good Data:
0.46578
12.314213
1.444876


Bad Data:
[2, Error: Could not calculate value.]
```

Comment: well thanks for the constructive nature of your comment. Since you have a better way would you be so kind as to post your own answer that isn't "the worst LINQ usage you've ever seen".

Comment: Main problem here is a fact, that your solution iterated over `data` `2+I` times, where `I` is number of incorrect rows - `IndexOf` iterates the collection from beginning every time it's called. You also `Parse` every line at least twice, and most of them three times (two `TryParse` and one `Parse` for good values). That's not really efficient, is it?  I've posted my answer, feel free to criticize it!

Comment: Let me just show you how I would write a comment when code could be made more efficient taken directly from your comments sans the nonconstructive portions. "Your solution iterated over data 2+I times, where I is number of incorrect rows - IndexOf iterates the collection from beginning every time it's called. You also Parse every line at least twice, and most of them three times (two TryParse and one Parse for good values). There is already Select overload with an index supplied.. using .Select((s, i) => i being the indexOf"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you don't like `foreach` loop here. LINQ uses it internally anyway, and as you've already realized there are some pros and cons of using LINQ and debugging is one of cons.

I would probably mix LINQ with `foreach` and end up with following:

```
// read all lines from file //
var file_contents = File.ReadAllLines("myfile.txt");

// set initial data list length to number of lines for better performance
var data = new List<double>(file_contents.Length);

// list for incorrect line numbers
var incorrectRows = new List<int>();

foreach (var x in file_contents.Select((s, i) => new {s, i}))
{
    // x.s - line string
    // x.i - line number

    double value;
    if (double.TryParse(x.s, out value))
        data.Add(value);        // add value, which was OK
    else
        incorrectRows.Add(x.i); // add index of incorrect value
}
```

That will prevent an exception at all and will give you line numbers for all incorrect values. It also iterate over `file_contents` just once and every value is being parsed only once.